# TF Keras: how to load weights for a sub model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm training a model that takes two inputs and makes a prediction. As part of the model, I want each input to be projected into an embedding space before being concatenated for the final layer.

After training, I would like to be able to re-create the embedder by itself using the final model weights.

As you can see in the code below, after training calling embedder.load_weights doesn't do anything, but model.load_weights does. I would like to be able to create the embedder without declaring the rest of the model as well.

What is going on with embedder.load_weights not doing anything and what is the right way to do this?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def get_embedder():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(inputs)
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

test_input1 = np.random.random((32, 3))
test_input2 = np.random.random((32, 3))
test_target = np.random.random((32, 1))

embedder = get_embedder()
input1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))
input2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))
embedding1 = embedder(input1)
embedding2 = embedder(input2)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(tf.concat([embedding1, embedding2], axis=-1))
model = tf.keras.Model([input1, input2], output)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), loss="mse")

# Train the model.
model.fit([test_input1, test_input2], test_target)
model.save("my_saved_model", save_format="tf")

print("post training embedder weights:")
print(embedder.get_weights())
# Just to change the embedder weights
model.fit([test_input1[0:1], test_input2[0:1]], test_target[0:1])
print("new embedder weights:")
print(embedder.get_weights())
# Notice that this silently fails to change the weights.
embedder.load_weights("my_saved_model/variables/variables")
print("WRONG original embedder weights:")
print(embedder.get_weights())
model.load_weights("my_saved_model/variables/variables")
print("RIGHT original embedder weights:")
print(embedder.get_weights())
```

Output:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 212ms/step - loss: 0.9330
post training embedder weights:
[array([[ 0.3181812 , -0.2883774 ],
       [-0.77182835,  0.3912304 ],
       [-0.7377591 ,  0.03317605]], dtype=float32), array([0.01441183, 0.02535881], dtype=float32)]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 115ms/step - loss: 0.2744
new embedder weights:
[array([[ 0.32533526, -0.27553943],
       [-0.76810485,  0.40208143],
       [-0.72922784,  0.04217484]], dtype=float32), array([0.02274978, 0.04046782], dtype=float32)]
WRONG original embedder weights:
[array([[ 0.32533526, -0.27553943],
       [-0.76810485,  0.40208143],
       [-0.72922784,  0.04217484]], dtype=float32), array([0.02274978, 0.04046782], dtype=float32)]
RIGHT original embedder weights:
[array([[ 0.3181812 , -0.2883774 ],
       [-0.77182835,  0.3912304 ],
       [-0.7377591 ,  0.03317605]], dtype=float32), array([0.01441183, 0.02535881], dtype=float32)]
```